# python3 kernel not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have problems starting a jupyter notebook with a python 3 kernel. As far as I remember things have worked before. Notebooks with Python 2.7 kernel are fine. I tried to update packages but finally, I don't know where to look for. I hope, I did not miss any solution which has been already posted. If so, I am sorry - but I spent quite some time to look for it.

For diagnostics:

```
(base) screening-mac-14-tb:jupiter-folder testuser$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /Users/testuser/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
  scijava    /Users/testuser/Library/Jupyter/kernels/scijava
  python2    /Users/testuser/anaconda/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
(base) screening-mac-14-tb:jupiter-folder testuser$ jupyter troubleshoot 
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
/Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
$PATH:
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/condabin
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /opt/X11/bin

sys.path:
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin
    /Users/testuser/CellProfiler
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python27.zip
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /Users/testuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa

sys.executable:
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin/python

sys.version:
    2.7.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) 
    [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)]

platform.platform():
    Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

which -a jupyter:
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin/jupyter
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin/jupyter
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin/jupyter
    /Users/testuser/anaconda/bin/jupyter

pip list:
    alabaster (0.7.9)
    anaconda-client (1.6.0)
    anaconda-navigator (1.5)
    anaconda-project (0.4.1)
    appnope (0.1.0)
    appscript (1.0.1)
    argcomplete (1.0.0)
    asn1crypto (0.24.0)
    astroid (1.4.9)
    astropy (1.3)
    Babel (2.3.4)
    backports-abc (0.5)
    backports.functools-lru-cache (1.5)
    backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
    backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
    beautifulsoup4 (4.5.3)
    bitarray (0.8.1)
    blaze (0.10.1)
    bokeh (0.12.4)
    boto (2.45.0)
    Bottleneck (1.2.0)
    cdecimal (2.3)
    cellh5 (1.3.0)
    centrosome (1.0.5)
    certifi (2018.11.29)
    cffi (1.9.1)
    chardet (3.0.4)
    chest (0.2.3)
    click (6.7)
    cloudpickle (0.2.2)
    clyent (1.2.2)
    colorama (0.3.7)
    conda (4.6.4)
    configobj (5.0.6)
    configparser (3.5.0)
    contextlib2 (0.5.4)
    cryptography (2.5)
    cycler (0.10.0)
    Cython (0.25.2)
    cytoolz (0.8.2)
    dask (0.13.0)
    datashape (0.5.4)
    decorator (4.0.11)
    dill (0.2.5)
    docutils (0.13.1)
    enum34 (1.1.6)
    et-xmlfile (1.0.1)
    fastcache (1.0.2)
    Flask (0.12)
    Flask-Cors (3.0.2)
    funcsigs (1.0.2)
    functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
    futures (3.0.5)
    gevent (1.2.1)
    greenlet (0.4.11)
    grin (1.2.1)
    h5py (2.7.1)
    HeapDict (1.0.0)
    hmmlearn (0.2.0)
    idna (2.8)
    imagesize (0.7.1)
    inflect (0.2.5)
    ipaddress (1.0.18)
    ipykernel (4.10.0)
    ipython (5.1.0)
    ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
    ipywidgets (5.2.2)
    isort (4.2.5)
    itsdangerous (0.24)
    javabridge (1.0.14)
    jdcal (1.3)
    jedi (0.9.0)
    Jinja2 (2.9.4)
    jsonschema (2.5.1)
    jupyter (1.0.0)
    jupyter-client (4.4.0)
    jupyter-console (5.0.0)
    jupyter-core (4.2.1)
    kiwisolver (1.0.1)
    lazy-object-proxy (1.2.2)
    libtiff (0.4.0)
    llvmlite (0.15.0)
    locket (0.2.0)
    lxml (3.7.2)
    MarkupSafe (0.23)
    matplotlib (2.2.2)
    mistune (0.7.3)
    mpmath (0.19)
    multipledispatch (0.4.9)
    MySQL-python (1.2.5)
    nbconvert (4.2.0)
    nbformat (4.2.0)
    networkx (1.11)
    nltk (3.2.2)
    nose (1.3.7)
    notebook (4.3.1)
    numba (0.30.1+0.g8c1033f.dirty)
    numexpr (2.6.1)
    numpy (1.11.3)
    numpydoc (0.6.0)
    odo (0.5.0)
    olefile (0.45.1)
    openpyxl (2.4.1)
    pandas (0.19.2)
    partd (0.3.7)
    pathlib2 (2.2.0)
    patsy (0.4.1)
    pep8 (1.7.0)
    pexpect (4.2.1)
    pickleshare (0.7.4)
    Pillow (5.0.0)
    pip (9.0.1)
    ply (3.9)
    prokaryote (1.0.11)
    prompt-toolkit (1.0.9)
    protobuf (2.6.1)
    psutil (5.0.1)
    ptyprocess (0.5.1)
    py (1.4.32)
    pyasn1 (0.1.9)
    PyAudio (0.2.7)
    pycosat (0.6.3)
    pycparser (2.17)
    pycrypto (2.6.1)
    pycurl (7.19.0)
    pyflakes (1.5.0)
    Pygments (2.1.3)
    pylint (1.6.4)
    pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
    pyparsing (2.1.4)
    PySocks (1.6.8)
    pytest (3.0.5)
    python-bioformats (1.0.8)
    python-dateutil (2.6.0)
    pytz (2016.10)
    PyYAML (3.12)
    pyzmq (16.0.2)
    QtAwesome (0.4.3)
    qtconsole (4.2.1)
    QtPy (1.2.1)
    redis (2.10.5)
    requests (2.21.0)
    rope (0.9.4)
    scandir (1.4)
    scikit-image (0.12.3)
    scikit-learn (0.18.1)
    scipy (0.19.0)
    seaborn (0.7.1)
    setuptools (40.8.0)
    simplegeneric (0.8.1)
    singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
    six (1.10.0)
    snowballstemmer (1.2.1)
    sockjs-tornado (1.0.3)
    Sphinx (1.5.1)
    spyder (3.1.2)
    SQLAlchemy (1.1.5)
    statsmodels (0.6.1)
    subprocess32 (3.2.7)
    sympy (1.0)
    tables (3.4.3)
    terminado (0.6)
    toolz (0.8.2)
    tornado (4.4.2)
    traitlets (4.3.1)
    unicodecsv (0.14.1)
    urllib3 (1.24.1)
    wcwidth (0.1.7)
    Werkzeug (0.11.15)
    wheel (0.29.0)
    widgetsnbextension (1.2.6)
    wrapt (1.10.8)
    wxPython (3.0.0.0)
    wxPython-common (3.0.0.0)
    xlrd (1.0.0)
    XlsxWriter (0.9.6)
    xlwings (0.10.2)
    xlwt (1.2.0)

conda list:
    # packages in environment at /Users/testuser/anaconda:
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    _license                  1.1                      py27_1  
    alabaster                 0.7.9                    py27_0  
    anaconda                  custom           py27h2cfa9e9_0  
    anaconda-client           1.6.0                    py27_0  
    anaconda-navigator        1.5.0                    py27_0  
    anaconda-project          0.4.1                    py27_0  
    appnope                   0.1.0                    py27_0  
    appscript                 1.0.1                    py27_0  
    argcomplete               1.0.0                    py27_1  
    asn1crypto                0.24.0                py27_1003    conda-forge
    astroid                   1.4.9                    py27_0  
    astropy                   1.3                 np111py27_0  
    babel                     2.3.4                    py27_0  
    backports                 1.0                      py27_0  
    backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                      py27_0    conda-forge
    backports_abc             0.5                      py27_0  
    beautifulsoup4            4.5.3                    py27_0  
    bitarray                  0.8.1                    py27_0  
    blas                      1.0                         mkl  
    blaze                     0.10.1                   py27_0  
    blosc                     1.14.0                        1    conda-forge
    bokeh                     0.12.4                   py27_0  
    boto                      2.45.0                   py27_0  
    bottleneck                1.2.0               np111py27_0  
    bzip2                     1.0.6                         1    conda-forge
    ca-certificates           2018.11.29           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
    cairo                     1.14.10                       0    conda-forge
    cdecimal                  2.3                      py27_2  
    certifi                   2018.11.29            py27_1000    conda-forge
    cffi                      1.9.1                    py27_0  
    chardet                   3.0.4                 py27_1003    conda-forge
    chest                     0.2.3                    py27_0  
    click                     6.7                      py27_0  
    cloudpickle               0.2.2                    py27_0  
    clyent                    1.2.2                    py27_0  
    colorama                  0.3.7                    py27_0  
    conda                     4.6.4                    py27_0    conda-forge
    conda-env                 2.6.0                         0    conda-forge
    configobj                 5.0.6                    py27_0  
    configparser              3.5.0                    py27_0  
    contextlib2               0.5.4                    py27_0  
    cryptography              2.5              py27ha12b0ac_0  
    curl                      7.62.0               ha441bb4_0  
    cycler                    0.10.0                   py27_0  
    cython                    0.25.2                   py27_0  
    cytoolz                   0.8.2                    py27_0  
    dask                      0.13.0                   py27_0  
    datashape                 0.5.4                    py27_0  
    decorator                 4.0.11                   py27_0  
    dill                      0.2.5                    py27_0  
    docutils                  0.13.1                   py27_0  
    entrypoints               0.2.2                    py27_0  
    enum34                    1.1.6                    py27_0  
    et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py27_0  
    fastcache                 1.0.2                    py27_1  
    ffmpeg                    3.2.4                         3    conda-forge
    flask                     0.12                     py27_0  
    flask-cors                3.0.2                    py27_0  
    fontconfig                2.12.6                        0    conda-forge
    freetype                  2.8.1                         0    conda-forge
    funcsigs                  1.0.2                    py27_0  
    functools32               3.2.3.2                  py27_0  
    futures                   3.0.5                    py27_0  
    get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py27_0  
    gettext                   0.19.8.1                      0    conda-forge
    gevent                    1.2.1                    py27_0  
    giflib                    5.1.4                         0    conda-forge
    glib                      2.55.0                        0    conda-forge
    graphite2                 1.3.11                        0    conda-forge
    greenlet                  0.4.11                   py27_0  
    grin                      1.2.1                    py27_3  
    h5py                      2.7.1                    py27_3    conda-forge
    harfbuzz                  1.7.6                         0    conda-forge
    hdf5                      1.10.1                        2    conda-forge
    heapdict                  1.0.0                    py27_1  
    icu                       58.2                          0    conda-forge
    idna                      2.8                   py27_1000    conda-forge
    imagesize                 0.7.1                    py27_0  
    ipaddress                 1.0.18                   py27_0  
    ipykernel                 4.10.0                   py27_0    conda-forge
    ipython                   5.1.0                    py27_1  
    ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0  
    ipywidgets                5.2.2                    py27_1  
    isort                     4.2.5                    py27_0  
    itsdangerous              0.24                     py27_0  
    jasper                    1.900.1                       4    conda-forge
    jbig                      2.1                           0  
    jdcal                     1.3                      py27_0  
    jedi                      0.9.0                    py27_1  
    jinja2                    2.9.4                    py27_0  
    jpeg                      9b                            0  
    jsonschema                2.5.1                    py27_0  
    jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_3  
    jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py27_0  
    jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py27_0  
    jupyter_core              4.2.1                    py27_0  
    kiwisolver                1.0.1                    py27_1    conda-forge
    lazy-object-proxy         1.2.2                    py27_0  
    libcurl                   7.62.0               h051b688_0  
    libffi                    3.2.1                         3    conda-forge
    libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
    libiconv                  1.15                          0    conda-forge
    libpng                    1.6.34                        0    conda-forge
    libssh2                   1.8.0                         1    conda-forge
    libtiff                   4.0.9                         0    conda-forge
    libwebp                   0.5.2                         7    conda-forge
    libxml2                   2.9.4                         0  
    libxslt                   1.1.29                        0  
    llvmlite                  0.15.0                   py27_0  
    locket                    0.2.0                    py27_1  
    lxml                      3.7.2                    py27_0  
    markupsafe                0.23                     py27_2  
    matplotlib                2.2.2                    py27_1    conda-forge
    mistune                   0.7.3                    py27_1  
    mkl                       2017.0.1                      0  
    mkl-service               1.1.2                    py27_3  
    mpmath                    0.19                     py27_1  
    multipledispatch          0.4.9                    py27_0  
    nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py27_0  
    nbformat                  4.2.0                    py27_0  
    networkx                  1.11                     py27_0  
    nltk                      3.2.2                    py27_0  
    nose                      1.3.7                    py27_1  
    notebook                  4.3.1                    py27_0  
    numba                     0.30.1              np111py27_0  
    numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py27_2  
    numpy                     1.11.3           py27h8a80b8c_4  
    numpydoc                  0.6.0                    py27_0  
    odo                       0.5.0                    py27_1  
    olefile                   0.45.1                   py27_0    conda-forge
    openblas                  0.2.20                        7    conda-forge
    opencv                    2.4.13              np111py27_1    conda-forge
    openpyxl                  2.4.1                    py27_0  
    openssl                   1.1.1a            h1de35cc_1000    conda-forge
    pandas                    0.19.2              np111py27_1  
    partd                     0.3.7                    py27_0  
    path.py                   10.0                     py27_0  
    pathlib2                  2.2.0                    py27_0  
    patsy                     0.4.1                    py27_0  
    pcre                      8.41                          1    conda-forge
    pep8                      1.7.0                    py27_0  
    pexpect                   4.2.1                    py27_0  
    pickleshare               0.7.4                    py27_0  
    pillow                    5.0.0                    py27_0    conda-forge
    pip                       9.0.1                    py27_1  
    pixman                    0.34.0                        1    conda-forge
    ply                       3.9                      py27_0  
    prompt_toolkit            1.0.9                    py27_0  
    protobuf                  2.6.1                    py27_1  
    psutil                    5.0.1                    py27_0  
    ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py27_0  
    py                        1.4.32                   py27_0  
    pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py27_0  
    pyaudio                   0.2.7                    py27_0  
    pycosat                   0.6.3           py27h1de35cc_1001    conda-forge
    pycparser                 2.17                     py27_0  
    pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py27_4  
    pycurl                    7.19.0                   py27_1  
    pyflakes                  1.5.0                    py27_0  
    pygments                  2.1.3                    py27_0  
    pylint                    1.6.4                    py27_1  
    pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py27_0  
    pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py27_0  
    pyqt                      5.6.0                    py27_1  
    pysocks                   1.6.8                 py27_1002    conda-forge
    pytables                  3.4.3                    py27_8    conda-forge
    pytest                    3.0.5                    py27_0  
    python                    2.7.6                         0  
    python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py27_0  
    python.app                1.2                      py27_4  
    pytz                      2016.10                  py27_0  
    pyyaml                    3.12                     py27_0  
    pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py27_0  
    qt                        5.6.2                h9e3eb04_4    conda-forge
    qtawesome                 0.4.3                    py27_0  
    qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py27_1  
    qtpy                      1.2.1                    py27_0  
    readline                  6.2                           2  
    redis                     3.2.0                         0  
    redis-py                  2.10.5                   py27_0  
    requests                  2.21.0                py27_1000    conda-forge
    rope                      0.9.4                    py27_1  
    ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py27_1  
    scandir                   1.4                      py27_0  
    scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py27_1  
    scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py27_1  
    scipy                     0.19.0              np111py27_0  
    seaborn                   0.7.1                    py27_0  
    setuptools                40.8.0                   py27_0    conda-forge
    simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_1  
    singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_0  
    sip                       4.18                     py27_0  
    six                       1.10.0                   py27_0  
    snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py27_0  
    sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py27_0  
    sphinx                    1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
    spyder                    3.1.2                    py27_0  
    sqlalchemy                1.1.5                    py27_0  
    sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
    ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_1  
    statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py27_1  
    subprocess32              3.2.7                    py27_0  
    sympy                     1.0                      py27_0  
    terminado                 0.6                      py27_0  
    tk                        8.5.18                        0  
    toolz                     0.8.2                    py27_0  
    tornado                   4.4.2                    py27_0  
    traitlets                 4.3.1                    py27_0  
    unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py27_0  
    urllib3                   1.24.1                py27_1000    conda-forge
    wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py27_0  
    werkzeug                  0.11.15                  py27_0  
    wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0  
    widgetsnbextension        1.2.6                    py27_0  
    wrapt                     1.10.8                   py27_0  
    wxpython                  3.0                      py27_0    anaconda
    x264                      20131218                      0    conda-forge
    xlrd                      1.0.0                    py27_0  
    xlsxwriter                0.9.6                    py27_0  
    xlwings                   0.10.2                   py27_0  
    xlwt                      1.2.0                    py27_0  
    xz                        5.2.2                         1  
    yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
    zlib                      1.2.11                        0    conda-forge
(base) screening-mac-14-tb:jupiter-folder testuser$
```

This is the first part of the output:

```
(base) screening-mac-14-tb:jupiter-folder testuser$ jupyter notebook
/Users/testuser/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.DeprecatedIn23,
[I 14:05:11.930 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/testuser/Work/jupiter-folder
[I 14:05:11.931 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 14:05:11.931 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=acbd88511cb7480ec77e1caa60d1cfbcf3a476301d888128
[I 14:05:11.931 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:05:11.932 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=acbd88511cb7480ec77e1caa60d1cfbcf3a476301d888128
[I 14:05:12.309 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 14:05:26.709 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 76b7a626-e3e3-4aa9-967c-7ab2335d0330
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x105144b70>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 605, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 536, in <lambda>
    self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda : self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    self.pre_handler_hook()
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 248, in pre_handler_hook
    self.saved_sigint_handler = signal(SIGINT, default_int_handler)
  File "/Users/testuser/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
[W 14:05:36.824 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 76b7a626-e3e3-4aa9-967c-7ab2335d0330
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`pip3 install jupyter`

`ipython kernel install --name=python3 --user`

this combination always helped me, it also allows you to create new jupyter kernel inside virtualenvironment.